# Reading csv values into Dictionary with Where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have a consistently-structured csv file. The first two fields contain location and category values.

Location + category entries are generally unique. However if they are duplicated, the third field will contain distinct values for each row in the set. Thus field1 + field2 + field3 will always form a unique key.

I want to return a list of dictionary objects for a given location + category pair, with the dictionary key as a string combining fields 1-3, and the dictionary value containing the entire row.

This is what I have so far but I can't get it working:

```
public static List<Dictionary> ItemEntries(string LocationAndCategory)
{
string fileOfLocations = @"C:\MyFile.csv"
return File.ReadAllLines(fileOfLocations).Where(line => line.Split(',')[0] + " " + line.Split(',')[1] == LocationAndCategory).Select(line => line.Split(',')).ToDictionary(data => data[0] + data[1] + data[2], data=> line);
}
```

Comment: But, is that throwing an exception or a result that you are not expecting?, Please, could you be more specific?

Comment: I get a build error: "Using the generic type 'System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>' requires 2 type arguments"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
//...
return (from line in File.ReadAllLines(fileOfLocations)
        let columns=line.Split(',')   // apply the Split just one time
        where columns[0]+" "+ columns[1] == LocationAndCategory   //apply your filter
        group line by columns[0]+columns[1]+columns[2] into g   //group the lines using the three columns to create a key
        select new {Key=g.Key, Lines= g.ToList()}).ToDictionary(e=>e.Key, e=>e.Lines);
```

Using method syntax would be something like this:

```
return File.ReadAllLines(fileOfLocations).Select(l=> new {Line=l, Columns=l.Split(',')})
                                         .Where(e=>e.Columns[0]+" "+e.Columns[1]==LocationAndCategory)
                                         .GroupBy(e=>e.Columns[0]+e.Columns[1]+e.Columns[2], e=>e.Line)
                                         .ToDictionary(g=>g.Key,g=>g.ToList() );
```

If the first row of your CSV start with headers you can call `Skip(1)` after call `ReadAllLines` method.

### Update

Maybe this is what you really are looking for:

```
public static Dictionary<string,string> ItemEntries(string LocationAndCategory)
{
    return File.ReadAllLines(fileOfLocations).Select(l=> new {Line=l, Columns=l.Split(',')})
                                             .Where(e=>e.Columns[0]+" "+e.Columns[1]==LocationAndCategory)
                                             .ToDictionary(e=>e.Columns[0]+e.Columns[1]+e.Columns[2],e=>e.Line);
}
```

PS: This is assuming that the combination of those three columns is unique, otherwise, `ToDictionary` will throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try. Can you tell me what your pros/cons would be regarding method syntax vs the first? I

Comment: None, query syntax is just sugar syntax. At the end if you use query syntax, later is  translated into method calls for the .NET common language runtime (CLR) when the code is compiled. Check this [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) page

Comment: Hm I can't get either of these approaches to work - different typing errors.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what is the issue? I wrote those queries on the fly, I fixed some typo errors in the firs one, did you find anything wrong in the second one?

Comment: Sure the first one is throwing: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' (CS0029) And Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>>' (CS0029)

Comment: The second one: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'  and Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>>'